# React Native - Native Base FAB (Floating Action Button): Clicking the FAB automatically calls sub-buttons 'onpress'

Tags: reactjs, react-native, uibutton, floating-action-button, native-base

I am currently trying to implement the floating action button (FAB) from the native-base framework. I simply copied the code, and added a single `onPress` method to one of the sub-buttoms (Facebook-Logo in this case). However, this `onPress` is triggered when I click the FAB button, instead of the facebook-button which should appear AFTER clicking the FAB button.

In short: 
desired behvaior:
1. click FAB button
2. due to number 1, let facebook button appear
3. click facebook button to trigger `onPress`

the behvaior I get:
1. click FAB button
2. `onPress` as defined in facebook's button is triggered

I have not really changed anything in the code, here is what it looks like:

```
<Fab
                active={this.state.fabActive}
                direction="up"
                containerStyle={{ marginLeft: 10 }}
                style={{ backgroundColor: '#5067FF' }}
                position="bottomRight"
                onPress={() => this.setState({ feedbackComponentVisible: !this.state.fabActive })}>
                <Icon name="share" />
                <Button style={{ backgroundColor: '#34A34F' }}>
                    <Icon name="logo-whatsapp" />
                </Button>
                <Button style={{ backgroundColor: '#3B5998' }} onPress={() => this.setState({feedbackComponentVisible: true})}>
                    <Icon name="logo-facebook" />
                </Button>
                <Button disabled style={{ backgroundColor: '#DD5144' }}>
                    <Icon name="mail" />
                </Button>
</Fab>
```

Answer (score 0):

Problem is this code segment changing the same state from both onPress functions.
According to this if `this.state.fabActive=false` then value will change to `true` when you click on the FAB button which you expecting from sub-button.
Try with two separate states, this should work.